# Time Limit Exceeded for search in rotated sorted array in C++ in InterviewBit problem under topic Binary Search

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

The problem is to search for an element in a sorted, rotated array in C++.
The approach that I have used is to find the pivot element index/ the minimum element index and then  to find the key either from a[pivot......end] or a[beg,....pivot] use binary search.

The time complexity to find the minimum element index is O(log n) and then for finding the element is also O(log n) and hence the overall time complexity will be O(log n)

But I am getting Time Limit Exceeded error
Here is my code :

```
int find_pivot(std::vector<int> a, int beg, int end)
{
    while(beg<=end)
    {
        int mid=(beg+end)/2;
        if(mid>0 && a[mid]<a[mid-1])
            return mid;
        else if(a[mid]>a[end])
            beg=mid+1;
        else
            end=mid;
    }
}

int search_element(std::vector<int> a, int key, int beg, int end)
{
    int pivot = find_pivot(a,0,a.size()-1);
    if(key>=a[pivot] && key<=a[end])
        beg=pivot;
    else
        end=pivot;
    while(beg<=end)
    {
        int mid=(beg+end)/2;
        if(key==a[mid])
            return mid;
        else if(key>a[mid])
            beg=mid+1;
        else
            end=mid-1;
    }
    return -1;
}

int Solution::search(const vector<int> &A, int B) {
    int n = A.size();
   int i = search_element(A, B, 0, n-1); 

    if (i != -1) 
    return i;
    else
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `if (i != -1) 
    return i;
    else
    return -1;` is is a much more complicated version of `return i;`

Comment: Noted ! But I don't think that is going to make a difference in the time complexity.

Comment: SO lately has been overwhelmed with these online quiz questions.  If anything, this question belongs on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Won't matter a bit. It just makes for easier and quicker reading.

Comment: *But I am getting Time Limit Exceeded* -- and that probably means you are going into an infinite loop.  Where is the test data?  If you claim this does a binary search, then there shouldn't be a time limit problem.  Even with a billion elements, you have to probe no more than 31 times.  Thus the only conclusion I see is that your code is buggy.

Comment: Generally when you get a Time Limit error from a judge it means that there is some sneaky trick you need to know or discover in order to eliminate a bunch of the work. Use what you have to further analyze the patterns and see if you can find a way to rewrite the program to skip some steps.

Comment: A : [ 1, 7, 67, 133, 178 ]
B : 1

Comment: @user4581301 -- I think the "sneaky trick" is binary search, but the OP probably has faulty code.

Comment: I just realized that it is going into infinite loop because of the test case. The input is sorted but it is not rotated.

Comment: Well, that makes sense.  A binary search just needs a few iterations to find or not find a value, even if there are billions (or even trillions) of elements.  That's why the only conclusion was that the function was faulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your find_pivot function, Lets say array is normally sorted [1,2,3,4,5].
Now when you call your find_pivot function , there will come a time when beg=0 and end =1.

Now , since mid=(beg+end/2)=0 your function will change end=mid which means end also becomes 0.

Now your beg=0 and end=0, now when the loop starts again
Mid = 0+0/2 and and this will keep on repeating.

Make some changes and I think the issue is when the array is normally sorted or when end=begin.

Comment: Yes, the program runs into an infinite loop when the input is sorted but not rotated. I didn't add the condition for when input it not rotated (since the problem clearly states that the input is sorted and rotated).